# Rendering bathymetry data in .cdf format on GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, bathymetry

How do I render the ocean depth data on GeoServer?

Answer (score 1):

You can find information on how to use NetCDF files in GeoServer in its documentation: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/netcdf/netcdf.html